Anyone has experience on using the newest acmart of Primary Article Template - LaTeX for ACM?
I have downloaded the latest Primary Article Template - LaTeX for ACM.  I am currently using:
Texmaker 5.1.3
(compiled with Qt 5.15.2)
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 by Pascal Brachet

I am using Quick Build to generate PDF. But it will not compile. I have reduced the latex to the minimal form.
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title Is Hope}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

The issue is caused by \maketitle on \section{Introduction}.  Deleting \section{Introduction} leads to correct output PDF.  There are two errors.  Both are:
! Undefined control sequence.
\MakeTextUppercase ...\oe \OE \@@text@case@aux
{upper}{#1}{#2}
l.9 \section{Introduction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,

I tried the latest version of TexMaker 5.1.4, same issue for the samples. But for my document, the log now says:
I can not figure out the reason from the full log.
Please help! Thanks!

Probably your tex system is to old. Show the full log.

Maybe \usepackage{textcase} would help if you use an older LaTeX release.

You may try Overleaf instead https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-primary-article-template/wbvnghjbzwpc

My 5.1.3 version was downloaded last year. The current version is 5.1.4.  I can hardly believe that it is already too old.  Still, I will try the newest version to see if it solved the problem.

I tried the latest TexMaker 5.1.4, same issue on the original

For future reference, the version of TeXMaker is less relevant than the version of TeX.  The first few lines of the .log file would show that version.

texmaker is just the editor that you used to write the file, it has no effect on the tex output or error messages.

I need to download both the latest MikTex and the latest TexMaker to solve this issue.

@Sebastiano but essentially this is the answer, the problem was caused by having an out of date tex system and updating it fixes the error.

@DavidCarlisle I have done a mistake. Excuse me.

It's unlikely both were needed, though.
